Calculating an aggregated relationship score based on number and strength of relationships
I am trying to work out the best way to calculate an aggregated score at company level. We hold relationship scores between an external contact and a staff member. Eg, Bill Bailey (company A) has a relationship score of 50 with John Terrance (our firm).
Bill Bailey may know more than one person.
I'd like to know the relationship strength at Company A which aggregates all the individual relationships that we have with people at Company A.
How would I best calculate the relationship strength which takes into consideration the number of relationships and the strength of relationships with a company?
Haven't managed to solve it yet
